# How to make rheoscopic fluid using glycol stearate flakes

Tags: everyday-chemistry, aqueous-solution, solutions, home-experiment, rheology

Rheoscopic fluid can be made by adding mica powder to water. I read that mica powder can settle and condense after sitting around for a long time. So I want to use glycol stearate flakes instead.

What process is required to turn them into a rheoscopic fluid? The manufacturer states the melting point to be $\pu{135-140 °F}$. Would I simply mix them into some water and raise the temp until they melt? Should it stay in suspension after cooling?

Comment: Being highly hydrophobic, I think that just like stearic acid (see link, p. 2: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.06120.pdf), glycol stearate microcrystals would disperse without completely dissolving.

I would say that vigorous low-temperature stirring and maybe crushing would work. Note that, as reported around the web, high temperature would partially dissolve them, creating disordered aggregates of stearate, which would imply a loss in its "rheoscopic" qualities.

Mica powder in contrast, which is absolutely insoluble in water, would resist high temperatures (eg. useful for showing convection)